# Convert 4-sat to 3-sat

Tags: boolean-algebra, satisfiability

I want to know in general how can I convert [$4-SAT$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) to **3-SAT**.

And I have a specific case that if you can help me optimize it to **3-SAT** it will be greate.

I want to do this so I be able to use **sat** solvers programs.

$(C  \lor  A  \lor  D) \land  (C  \lor  B  \lor  D) \land  (\lnot C  \lor  A  \lor  \lnot D) \land  (\lnot C  \lor  B  \lor  \lnot D) \land  (C  \lor  \lnot A  \lor  \lnot B   \lor  \lnot D) \land  (\lnot C  \lor  \lnot A  \lor  \lnot B  \lor  D)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every clause is of the form $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3 \vee x_4)$, where $x_i$, $i \in [4]$ is a literal. Replace every such clause with two clauses $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee z) \wedge (\neg z \vee x_3 \vee x_4)$, where $z$ is a fresh variable. You can then verify that if some setting of $x_i$'s satisfies the original clause, you can find a setting of $z$ such that the two clauses are satisfied.

However, note that if you want to use a SAT solver, none of this is needed. A standard SAT solver can handle clauses of any length, and different clauses can be of different length.